# autoscroll to a specific position in page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iis

With this url https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386013/, the page would scroll to the top edge of the section(div) with id `answer-2386013`

[image]

and the url automatically changes to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements/2386013#2386013`

with this url https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214080/how-do-i-complete-the-sentence-if-you-dont-mind/214113?noredirect=1#comment455655_214113

[image]

the page scroll a little more, to the specific comment (div) section in that answer

How does SE site implement this feature?

I understand the `noredirect=1` part is a parameter of URL. I also understand the `455655` part is id of `<li>` element, which contains the div (comment section)

```
<li id="comment-455655">
```

I don't understand this the whole process of the feature. I guess this is a feature of IIS server + some protocol of HTML or JS + a feature of chrome. So, what are they, could someone please give some keywords I can dig with? Thanks in advance.

---

just padding `#comment455655_214113` or `#comment-455655` to the `a/...` url does not work

```
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/214113?noredirect=1#comment455655_214113
```

Comment: can you provide us your HTML code? also try to expand your link with `#{YOUR_ELEM_ID}`

Comment: @SametC There are 2 clickable urls, each would link you to an actual page, which contains the whole HTML code. If some specific part needs to be copied to here, I am willing to do that. directly expanding does not work either.